# information in registry

Tags: c#, winforms, registry

AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("").Version.ToString()  will give the version number ,,but i need to get version number from registry

registry path is under MY computer -> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->

leaf->monitor here current version file is there,,from there we need to

fetch version number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following code to get the version key value:

```
RegistryKey key= Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE").OpenSubKey("leaf").OpenSubKey("monitor ");
string version = key.GetValue("version");
```

Edit:
check now :)

Comment: here key and version are integer type or?

Comment: Error 1 The name 'key' does not exist in the current context F:\versionnum\versionnum\Form1.cs 40 14 versionnum


Error 2 The name 'version' does not exist in the current context F:\versionnum\versionnum\Form1.cs 41 13 versionnum

Comment: i inserted  Microsoft.Win32; namespace here

Answer (score 3):

Wael's code works fine, but there's a couple other (slightly syntactically cleaner) ways to do it, for example:

- `OpenSubKey` knows how to open several subkeys at once:

`RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\leaf\monitor");`

- Additionally, if you *only* need to get a value, which your question asks about, it's even simpler (and this allows you to set a fallback value if your target key doesn't exist, avoiding a thrown exception if you use `OpenSubKey`):

`string version = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\leaf\monitor", "version", "0");`

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) the class that allows you to read and write windows registy. All you need to do with it is to find the proper value to read.